# ModernCV remove period under subsection

Tags: moderncv

I have been trying to figure how to remove the period under my subsection title in my CV. This is what I have in one of my sections.

[image]

```
\section{Honors and Awards}
\subsection{Academic}
\vspace{-5mm}
\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item {Honor 1}, 2012 - Present
    \item {Honor 2}, 2015 - Present
    \item {Honor 3}, 2013 - 2015
\end{itemize}
}
```

In the image you can see a period under the A in Academic. If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embedded in the construction of the `\cventry` and is *specific* to the `\moderncvstyle` you choose. In your particular case, the `casual` style's `\cventry` inserts a `.`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut% <---------------------------------- '.' & \strut inserted
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

You can remove this `.` insertion globally via an [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) patch:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.}{}{}{}
```

The above can be inserted in the preamble *after* loading the style.